# No response from spring boot app on VPS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I developed spring boot app. I prepared it with embedded tomcat. When I run that jar on my computer it all works fine. But when I run same app on VPS it is initialized, on first request it prints that dispatcherServlet is initialized but there is no any other response from it. Browser keeps connection and the response never comes. I tried running it on other ports and similar, but there is no luck in that. The first try, when I just run app it worked. But then I tried to run it in background and from that point on, it never returned any response.

I believe that it receives request, because it prints that dispacherServlet initialization. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What is meant by VPS  ?

Comment: Virtual Private Server

Comment: Can you run `tracert/traceroute` to reach the springboot app?

Comment: if you have configured the springboot `actuators`, you could look for `trace`. This will tell you whether the server received the request from the browser/not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your firwall restriction. try to allow connection to your port .if you are using centos 7 try this command

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
```

replace 8080 with your port . if you are using iptables service .  try :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080-j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

I observe the same behavior with my Spring Boot application. But if I wait long enough, I have this message:

```
o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [224,707] milliseconds.
```

It probably means that your VPS has a weak entropy source and it could takes a (very) long time before full startup.

According to the [tomcat wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp):

> Tomcat 7+ heavily relies on SecureRandom class to provide random values for its session ids and in other places. Depending on your JRE it can cause delays during startup if entropy source that is used to initialize SecureRandom is short of entropy.

You can use a non-blocking entropy source by using the system property:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

It has some security implications, read [this question on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key) for details.